# How does avrdude with AVR-ISP-MKII respond when no target board is connected?

Tags: avr, avrdude, isp

How does avrdude with [AVR-ISP-MK2](https://www.olimex.com/Products/AVR/Programmers/AVR-ISP-MK2/) respond when no target board is connected?

I'm trying to troubleshoot my set-up, and would like to know if the problem lies between the laptop and programmer or between the programmer and target board.

For me, this avrdude command gives the [same result](http://pastebin.com/tCbJGkTn) regardless of whether the target board is connected or not. It doesn't matter if the file exists or not.

```
# avrdude -c avrispmkII -p m328 -U flash:w:flashled.hex
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found AVRISP mkII, serno: 000200012345
avrdude: Sent: . [01]
avrdude: usbdev_recv_frame(): usb_bulk_read(): Input/output error
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: Sent: . [01]
avrdude: usbdev_recv_frame(): usb_bulk_read(): Input/output error
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: Sent: . [01]
avrdude: usbdev_recv_frame(): usb_bulk_read(): Input/output error
avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: What commands are you running?

Comment: @coding_corgi I'm on Arch Linux x86_64 and have tried `avrdude -c avrispmkII -p m328 -U flash:w:filename.hex`. I've already updated the AVR-ISP-mk2 firmware using Atmel Flip to the one that handles avrdude and libusb.

Comment: Ok, well, i had trouble with my AVR ISP MKII on Ubuntu (until it blew up) and i was getting similar errors, are you compiling .c/.cpp files?

Comment: @coding_corgi Yes, I'm compiling .c files using avr-gcc. But that doesn't matter: I get the same behaviour regardless of whether the .hex file exists or whether the target board is connected to the programmer.

Comment: This might be the point where you want to run it under another operating system long enough to verify that it actually works, and that it is properly connected to your target board.  Perhaps they've gone and adjusted the protocol in some way which isn't expected.  You might also check if you have permission to the USB device node, though I'm not sure that not having that wouldn't have caused an earlier failure.  Finally, if you just need to get something programmed, an ISP sketch on an Arduino board generally works (though you'll manage to find those who have had trouble with that too)

Comment: If I look at these error messages, I get the impression that the protocol stack for talking to the programmer over USB is missing. Is `uisp - Micro In-System Programmer for Atmel's AVR MCUs` installed? Don't know how to check that on Arch your Google is as good as mine.

Comment: @jippie It seems to me as if uisp and avrdude are two different programs that can be used to communicate with programmers over USB.

Comment: My bad, you are right sorry for the confusion. Is there anything in `dmesg` after you connect the programmer? Try disconnect; `sudo dmesg -c; clear`; reconnect `sudo dmesg -c`.

Comment: @jippie: It is detected: `[43011.039111] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[43013.342476] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
`

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thank you. I did that and have now managed to program the atmega from a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

Update: **README.xcompile.20180518** is in the same [repository](https://github.com/brettyhale/AVR-OSX-and-Olimex-ISP-MK2), but has been revised for the latest stable gcc (8.1.0), binutils (2.30), as well as some other refinements. The avrdude-6.3 patch remains *alarmingly* relevant. Hope this helps...

---

Update: I've retained a [github](https://github.com/brettyhale/AVR-OSX-and-Olimex-ISP-MK2) repository with full instructions for building the cutting-edge AVR GNU toolchain (including avr-gcc 7.2.0 and avr-libc 2.0.0), as well as patching avrdude-6.3 to eliminate USB I/O errors.

The instructions are focused on OS X (using MacPorts), but should be easy to adapt for Unix / BSD hosts.

It also provides instructions for using [`dfu-programmer`](https://dfu-programmer.github.io/) to flash the Olimex AVR-ISP-MK2 for `libusb`-based firmware, overwriting the factory default `AVR Studio` firmware.

Since then, I've had no issues. I cobbled together a minimal programmer board with a 40 PDIP ZIF socket that draws 5V power from the AVR-ISP-MK2 with 5V:ON jumper setting.

[image: good enough for quick programming!]

Simple veroboard implementation for quick and dirty programming...

---

**Older Instructions:**

I know this is a late answer - but the [Olimex AVR-ISP-MKII](https://www.olimex.com/Products/AVR/Programmers/AVR-ISP-MK2/open-source-hardware) needs a firmware upgrade for use with avrdude (as opposed to AVR studio - see documentation).

Since I'm on OSX, the Atmel Flip utility wasn't a convenient option. Instead, I grabbed [dfu-programmer](http://dfu-programmer.sourceforge.net/), and flashed the programmer with the firmware `libUSB-AVRISP-MKII.hex` available from Olimex:

1. Connect the programmer, and press the upgrade pin - the LEDs should turn off.

> ```
> dfu-programmer at90usb162 erase
> dfu-programmer at90usb162 flash libUSB-AVRISP-MKII.hex
> dfu-programmer at90usb162 start
> ```

At this point, the orange and red LEDs were on.

You may have to tweak the `dfu-programmer` source, if `libusb-1.0` (required) lives somewhere besides `/usr/include`. I'm considered submitting an improved `configure.ac` and build system. (MacPorts users can install the `dfu-programmer` and `dfu-utils` packages.)

Plugging the ICSP10 into my cheap [AVR-P40-8535](https://www.olimex.com/Products/AVR/Proto/AVR-P40-8535-8MHz/) board, with an ATmega8535 in the socket (the MKII jumpers set to ON:5V) :

running: `avrdude -c avrisp2 -p m8535 -P usb`

returned the correct device signature `"0x1e9308"` for the ATmega8535.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did manage to update the firmware using Atmel Flip, but that didn't change the results. I got it working on a Windows machine, so I haven't spent any more time trying to fix the Linux set-up.