# Can AVR ISP mkII programmer be used in Mac OS?

Tags: avr, avrdude

I'm trying to program an ATmega644A. It works fine from Linux, but when I try the same project with the same programmer, an Olimex AVR ISP mkII, I get the following error:

```
avrdude -p ATmega644 -c avrispmkII -P usb -b 115200 -F -U flash:w:build/controller.hex

avrdude: stk500v2_recv_mk2: error in USB receive
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading |                                                    | 0% 0.00savrdude: usbdev_send(): wrote -34 out of 8 bytes, err = Result too large
avrdude: stk500_send_mk2(): failed to send command to serial port
make: *** [flash] Error 1
```

My AVR toolchain, including avrdude, comes from MacPorts, and I see libusb in /opt/local/lib too. I've tried as a normal user and as root (Linux requires root for USB access with libusb). What could the problem be?

Comment: I've also tried the avrdude binary from Arduino IDE with the same result.

Comment: I have an old laptop with a working mkII, so it's possible, somehow. However, it's been a while since I used it, I don't remember how I set it up, and it's still running OS 10.6, or maybe even 10.5.

Comment: Can you give us the version of your `avrdude` binary?

Comment: @Turbo J It's 5.11.1 (which is the latest, I believe) -- the same as the version I'm running on Linux.

Comment: @Derecho - I just answered a similar question [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74298/how-does-avrdude-with-avr-isp-mkii-respond-when-no-target-board-is-connected/79122#79122).